# capabilities jqGrid - Max no of rows it can render (paging off and virtual scrolling off)

Tags: jqgrid

I have a question regarding capabilities jqGrid. We want to turn paging off and load all the data on the client side without implementing virtual  scrolling (paging turned off as well). How many records can the jqGrid handle realistically as we have been trying to load 50,000 records * 20 columns and it seems to blow up (Note: Virtual Scrolling turned off and Paging turned off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it's good idea. No user are able to look through 1 million cells. So you want to send 99,9% (or more) unneeded data to the client. What you really need is implementation of the subject oriented *filtering* of the data.

The performance of the grid will be mostly depend from the JavaScript engine of the web browser which you use. Nobody can get you common recommendation for IE6 and Chrome 19 because of very different JavaScript performance.

In any way I am sure that you have to implement paging, sorting and filtering *on the server side*. I think it's really required in case of 1 million cells of data.