# Load server data greater than 2147483647 bytes in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid to display data containing more than 17000 records which exceeds max limit set to maxJsonLength. This causes jqGrid to display error while loading the data & unable to display data in grid.

Comment: May be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209308/capabilities-jqgrid-max-no-of-rows-it-can-render-paging-off-and-virtual-scrol) will help you

Comment: Agree with Oleg at the above link. You are starting to hit the upper limit of rows allowed on client side. For your sanity (and that of your users), you need to start looking at server-side solutions that limit the amount of data returned to the client at any one time.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I will implement server side paging & sorting to narrow down the amount of data transferred from server to client.